# Comparing a float and its copy

Tags: java, c, comparison, double, malloc

I know that comparing two `doubles` is problematic if they are obtained from different calculations. But does this also hold in the case when one of them is a copy (in value) of the other. The following lines explain the scenario. If I have a problem like this,

```
double a,b;
a=randdouble();/*some double value*/
b=a;
```

Then,

Q1) Is the comparison `a==b` always guaranteed to return `true` in case of the C compiler (i have `gcc 6.1.1`)?

Q2) Would the above answer remain the same if I am allocating variables `a` and `b` in heap memory using `malloc`?

Q3) Would the above answers remain the same if I replace C compiler with a JAVA compiler (I am using `Open JDK 1.7.0`) with the necessary syntax changes ofcourse.

Edit 1 : The numbers `a` and `b` are `!= NaN`

Comment: 1) No, 2) yes, 3) yes

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why would `b=a` not result in `b==a` being true.  This is a direct copy of memory or a register.

Comment: @JoshSanford The question is about *guarantee*.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Out of curiosity why would 1 be no? I though comparison with == would always return true as long as the numbers are the same.

Comment: @SomeStudent There is not necessarily a case it would. but the fact (AFAIK) that there is just no such a guarantee in the standard.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I see. Yeah reason I was wondering is that I know that == does not work on objects like String, but numerical values should be fine unless I assume it was declared a pointer in which case it will point to different memory locations and will require de-referencing first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: The comparison is not guaranteed to evaluate to true, for the simple reason that `NaN` compares unequal to itself. There might be other cases too, but `NaN` is an obvious counterexample.

Q2: It makes no difference where the variables reside in memory.

Q3: I would expect Java to behave similarly.

This special case aside, I do believe the Standard does not give such a guarantee:

Imagine an ABI where `double` expressions are evaluated and values are returned with 80 bit precision (Intel 80x87 stack) but stored as 64 bit IEEE-754 doubles.  Even if `randdouble()` is defined to return a `double`, as opposed to `long double`, its return value may be more precise than the value stored into `a` or `b`.  Depending on how the compiler optimises the various expressions between the `randdouble()` function call and the comparison `a == b`, it may end up comparing the 80 bit precise return value with its close cousin obtained by converting to 64 bit and back to 80 bit.  The comparison would fail if precision was lost in the conversion.  I shall try and find a proper reference from the Standard to support this, but it seems plausible, and albeit whether `a` or `b` are local variables or stored on the heap might make a difference in the sequence of conversions performed, it would still be ill-advised to assume any guarantee for one or the other situations.

Comment: I am making the failsafe check on presence of `NaN`. I'll update the question about absence of `NaN`. Can you update your answer accordingly?

Comment: The checks you are making do not change the fact.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How is that? Can a `pseudoRandom` generator yield a `NaN` ?

Comment: Your question is about general FP workings and not about RNG or whatever special cases. At least this is how I and the answers author understand it.

Answer (score 2):

As another answer said NaN is always guaranteed to be different. This is a definition of IEEE-754 floating point standard. Both C and Java use this for their float and double bit representations and thus treat NaN as different.

```
a=Double.NaN;
b=a;

if (a==b)   // <--- comparison will fail.
```

But for all other values that comparison will behave according to the IEEE-754 bit pattern of the value. If the bit representation of the two variable is identical then that comparison will yield true.

So for your example using randdouble() your comparison of a==b will always yield true since you literally copy the bit representation from a to be in the assignment of b (assuming randdouble() can never return NaN).

That being said... you shouldn't ever rely on exact comparisons of floating point values in code. It is very rare your comparison values are arrived at through direct assignment from each other as in our trivial example here. They are usually arrived at through some computations. Each side of the comparison is often arrived at through a different series of computations. The computations often yield slightly different results in the bit representations due to the accumulated errors inherent to IEEE-754 limitations.

So, memory locations don't matter either since the bit patterns are the same regardless of where they are stored.

It also won't matter between C or Java (or any other language that uses IEEE-754 floating point representation).

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the assignment operator is yielding the exact bit copy? Is it guaranteed that the comparison operation is always returning true in case is exact bit copies (with the NaN exception)? I don't think so, but will look for reference.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think that is the crux of my dilemma. Is the assignment operator yielding an exact Bit copy.

Comment: I think you should not rely on this. If you really want to do the exact copy of an object and compare it bitwise, use `memcpy` and `memcmp`. I might be wrong here, though, as I don't find good reference..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks. Your comment has helped me to rephrase the question more appropriately. Lets wait for some more answers and may be references.